# Unexpected XML output in SOAP request

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I've been wrestling with this for a day now and I can't get my SOAP-request formatted correctly. This is how my Soap request is built up:

```
SoapObject request =  new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,  search);
SoapObject context =  new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "context");

request.addProperty("pi_csecurity_data", "security token ");

SoapObject mainclass = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "mainclass");
mainClass.addAttribute("adm_nr", "621");
mainClass.addAttribute("main_comp_code", "*");

context.addProperty("itmpMcomp", mainClass);
//also tried context.addSoapObject(mainclass); here
request.addSoapObject(context);
```

This is my ouput:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header/>
<v:Body>
    <n0:search id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="namespace">
        <pi_csecurity_data i:type="d:string">security token</pi_csecurity_data>
        <n0:context i:type="n0:context">
            <n0:mainclass i:type="n0:mainclass" adm_nr="621" main_comp_code="*"/>
        </n0:context>
    </n0:search>
</v:Body>
```

As you can probably see, I'm missing my closing tag for 
      < n0:mainclass >

Any thoughts anyone? :)

Comment: no you are not. a tag `<tag />` is considered to be closed. a tag `<tag>` is considered to be still opened.

Answer (score 0):

A tag does not always have to be :

```
<tag>...</tag>
```

If the tag has only attributes like in your case this syntax is also correct

```
<tag />
```